# How to push UIViewController overCurrentContext using UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIViewController that contains a UITabBar. I want to push a new UIViewController that covers the current context (so during the animation it shows the new UIViewController covering the UITabBar). How can I do this?

I have tried using the following to push the view but this is not pushed over the UITabBar.

```
let vc = ViewController2()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

I also thought that maybe I could just hide the UITabBar on ViewController2's viewWillAppear and show it on its viewWilDisappear; however, this just makes the UITabBar appear halfway through the dismissal (it looks really bad if you slowly slide to dismiss the view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In storyboard, go to the `UIViewController` you are going to push.
Go to attributes inspector and check "Hide Bottom Bar on Push"

This can also be done programmatically:

```
let vc = viewController1()
vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! I edited your answer to include information on how to do this segue programatically!

Comment: Sure, you are welcome ;D. I am new to swift too, been there with this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You must use presentViewController, not push.